# PDO cannot find ODBC driver after update even if the driver is still there

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

I update the server os from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 (actually 20.04 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04).
In my PHP 8.1.2 I try to connect to a remote MSSQL database in this way:

```
$SERVER = "192.168.2.51";
$DATABASE = "DB_NAME";
$DRIVER = "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1";
const USERNAME = "username";
const PASSWORD = "password";

$db = new PDO("odbc:driver=$DRIVER;server=$SERVER;database=$DATABASE", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Until 21.10 the connection was fine. Now I get this poor exception message:

```
object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(21) "could not find driver" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" ["line":protected]=> int(25) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" ["line"]=> int(25) ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [1]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(25) "/home/user/www/tables.php" ["line"]=> int(2) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" } ["function"]=> string(7) "require" } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["errorInfo"]=> NULL }
```

So it says `could not find driver` but the driver is actually there:

```
$ ls -l /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2063888 Feb  8 23:06 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
```

Is there something different in PHP 8? I didn't find anything about.

Comment: msodbc is currently only [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17) on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 21.04 and 21.10. Although the old driver file is still there probably one of its dependencies has been removed/upgraded during the dist-upgrade and is no longer compatible, so the library cannot be loaded.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning and what is this directory? https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so in 22.04 is not possible to connect to a MSSQL database?

Comment: I'm sure Microsoft will provide updates in due course, but it's currently not supported.

Comment: Upgrades from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 aren't actually fully supported yet either; it is from 21.10 (which isn't LTS), but upgrades from the prior LTS aren't normally enabled until after the .1  release (22.04.1 here)  is out. Part of that is to address any bugs that are missed, and improve stability; which many 3rd party providers will be addressing in their releasing in time for the .1 release. This is why it's also strongly recommended to check the things you *need* are supported on the new version of the OS. Many didn't (and still have not) upgraded to Windows 11 for this very reason too.

Comment: @Larnu actually I didn't upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 directly. But I did 20.04 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04 (I'm going to update the question). It's hard for me to know in advance all the things that could go wrong... I was sure that a basic thing like a db connection in PHP should have no problem.

Comment: In reference to your comment about the `22.04` package folder... it exists, but msodbc17 doesn't exist there, e.g.: `ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --yes msodbcsql17` when using it fails with `E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning of course, that's the problem :-) anyway I was expecting msodbcsql18...

Comment: That isn't there either. This is another good reason to put all of your dev stuff inside Docker containers and ignore the host OS.